# Javascript return confirm() when input name=confirm gives confirm is not a function

Tags: javascript, html, input, confirm

My code shows this error in the console:

> Uncaught TypeError: confirm is not a function

I can resolve it by renaming the input to something other then "confirm".
Why would naming an input conflict with JavaScript's confirm function?

```html
<form action="" method="POST">
  <input type="text" name="confirm">
  <input type="submit" onclick="return confirm('Text')">
</form>
```

Comment: "Why would naming an input conflict with javascripts confirm function?" - because someone at Netscape or Microsoft thought it would be a good idea back in 1997.

Comment: Try `window.confirm` instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In JavaScript, the names of input elements become properties of the associated form object. In your case, the input named "confirm" becomes a property of its form, which [shadows](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5373899/924299) the [`confirm` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/confirm) inherited from the [`window` object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window).

`window.confirm` => `form.confirm`
`<input type="text" name="confirm">` => `form.confirm`

As [mentioned by Dai](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67082443/javascript-return-confirm-when-input-name-confirm-gives-confirm-is-not-a-funct#comment118574290_67082443) in comments above, you can use `window.confirm()` to ensure that you access the `confirm` method of the `window` object.

```html
<form action="" method="POST">
  <input type="text" name="confirm">
  <input type="submit" onclick="return window.confirm('Text')">
</form>
```

Or, as referenced in your question, use a different input name:

```html
<form action="" method="POST">
  <input type="text" name="confirmation">
  <input type="submit" onclick="return confirm('Text')">
</form>
```

---

For more reference, also see:

[HTMLFormElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input#HTMLFormElement.elements)

> Warning: Avoid giving form elements a name that corresponds to a built-in property of the form, since you would then override the predefined property or method with this reference to the corresponding input.

[input name called submit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34525350/why-the-form-not-submitting-using-javascript-when-input-name-called-submit)
[confirm is not a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8059818/javascript-error-says-confirm-is-not-a-function)
[confirm not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37574999/jquery-confirm-not-working-after-first-click#)